# Inserting a list item via REST in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I have a .NET project that needs to add a list item to a Sharepoint 2010 list. After doing a bit of reading I though that using the RESTful services that come with SharePoint 2010 would be a good way to do this.

When I run the code, I have no errors returned and if I run the REST service _vti_bin/listdata.svc/ReturnToWork I can see my new entries in the list. However, when I browse my list via the SharePoint site, the entries are not there.

My code is:-

```
AttendDataContext context = new AttendDataContext(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMS.SharePoint.URL"]));
    string sUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMS.SharePoint.UserName"];
    string sPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMS.SharePoint.Password"];
    string sDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMS.SharePoint.Domain"];      

    public void AddReturnToWork(tAbsence oAbsence, tEmployee oManager)
    {
        ReturnToWorkItem oRTWItem = new ReturnToWorkItem();
        oRTWItem.Title = String.Format("{0}, {1} ({2}) : {3}", oAbsence.tEmployee.LastName, oAbsence.tEmployee.FirstName,
            oAbsence.tEmployee.EmployeeNo, oAbsence.AbsenceStartDate);
        oRTWItem.Site = oAbsence.tEmployee.Site;
        oRTWItem.Department = oAbsence.tEmployee.Department;
        oRTWItem.Manager = String.Format("{0}, {1} ({2})", oManager.LastName, oManager.FirstName, oManager.EmployeeNo);
        oRTWItem.AbsenceID = oAbsence.AbsenceID;
        oRTWItem.Employee = String.Format("{0}, {1} ({2})", oAbsence.tEmployee.LastName, oAbsence.tEmployee.FirstName,
            oAbsence.tEmployee.EmployeeNo);
        oRTWItem.AbsenceStartDate = oAbsence.AbsenceStartDate;
        oRTWItem.ReasonForAbsence = oAbsence.Reason;
        oRTWItem.RTWDate = oAbsence.RTWDate;
        oRTWItem.WorksAccident = false;
        oRTWItem.AccidentDate = oAbsence.AbsenceStartDate;
        oRTWItem.PINs = String.Format("{0}{1}", oAbsence.tEmployee.PIN, oManager.PIN);
        oRTWItem.EmployeePin = oAbsence.tEmployee.PIN;
        oRTWItem.ManagerPin = oManager.PIN;
        ReturnToWorkRTWStatusValue oRTWValue = new ReturnToWorkRTWStatusValue();
        oRTWValue.Value = "New";
        oRTWItem.RTWStatus = oRTWValue;

        context.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sUserName, sPassword, sDomain);

        context.AddToReturnToWork(oRTWItem);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Can anybody advise what I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies. It turns out the code was adding the records, but due to the volume of records already in the list I was filtering to find the records and the column I was filtering on (RTWStatus) was not populated with the value 'New' that I expected.

Just for information purposes, I've rejigged the code anyway to be slightly more readable (IMHO) and displayed below

```
context.AddToReturnToWork(
    new ReturnToWorkItem()
    {
        Title = String.Format("{0}, {1} ({2}) : {3}", oAbsence.tEmployee.LastName,
        oAbsence.tEmployee.FirstName, oAbsence.tEmployee.EmployeeNo,
            oAbsence.AbsenceStartDate),
        Site = oAbsence.tEmployee.Site,
        Department = oAbsence.tEmployee.Department,
        Manager = String.Format("{0}, {1} ({2})", oManager.LastName, oManager.FirstName, oManager.EmployeeNo),
        AbsenceID = oAbsence.AbsenceID,
        Employee = String.Format("{0}, {1} ({2})", oAbsence.tEmployee.LastName,
            oAbsence.tEmployee.FirstName, oAbsence.tEmployee.EmployeeNo),
        AbsenceStartDate = oAbsence.AbsenceStartDate,
        ReasonForAbsence = oAbsence.Reason,
        RTWDate = oAbsence.RTWDate,
        WorksAccident = false,
        AccidentDate = oAbsence.AbsenceStartDate,
        PINs = String.Format("{0}{1}", oAbsence.tEmployee.PIN, oManager.PIN),
        EmployeePin = oAbsence.tEmployee.PIN,
        ManagerPin = oManager.PIN,
        RTWStatus = new ReturnToWorkRTWStatusValue()
        {
            Value = "New"
        }
    }
);
```

The RTWStatus still isn't being populated, but that's another problem entirely!

Comment: Just for completeness....the issue with populating the RTWStatus column, which is a choice field, was resolved by using this instead:-

    RTWStatusValue = "New"

Fiddler is a great help for checking the REST queries :-)